# how do i import github repo code into mt client side-js?

Tags: javascript, npm, require, client-side

im trying to import github repository(public) named zipcelx into my client side js , and all i see is an option to download it from npm(which i also cant understand- would be glad if someone could explain how a module that suppose to be used on the client side could be helpfull with npm)
ive just tried to require it on a script tag as a cdn, and the source code contains a bouch of "import" methods, which i cant understand also...

this is the github repo : https://github.com/egeriis/zipcelx/wiki/How-to-use

it will be great if someone could explain this whole idea
much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use npm command like this

```
npm i https://github.com/egeriis/zipcelx/tarball/master
```

Forturnately you can also set it on your package json

```
dependencies:{
 "zipcelx": "https://github.com/egeriis/zipcelx/tarball/master"
}
```

so normal npm install will work

Comment: Yes but npm installs packages on your server side js, right? So you are requiring them using require method , but my question is how you can use npm for client side js packages